# how to count word length in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

i have loop data like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11;i++){
console.log(i); 
}
```

my question how to get word length so i want make result like this:

```
0 <-- this length is 1
1 <-- this length is 1
2 <-- this length is 1
3 <-- this length is 1
4 <-- this length is 1
5 <-- this length is 1
6 <-- this length is 1
7 <-- this length is 1
8 <-- this length is 1
9 <-- this length is 1
10 <-- this length is 2
```

Comment: Use `i.toString().length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse it to string with [**toString()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function and then get the [**length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) of that `string`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 11;i++){
  console.log(i + ' <- this length is ' + i.toString().length); 
}
```

Comment: owh... i see :(  i try like thats before,but not work,but when i see you'r answer i remember now, i forget to  use "()",so my code before like this: i.toString.length; <<so i get undefined :D hahha thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    console.log(i + " <-- this length is " + i.toString().length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11;i++){
    console.log(i + ' <- this length is ' + (i+'').length);
}
```